# KQL - logical processing of an KQL query

Tags: azure, kql

So, I was wondering what is the logical processing of an KQL query but couldn't find something relevant so far over the web.

If in SQL we have `FROM` clause first, `ON` second, `OUTER` clause third and so on, what would be the equivalent for it in KQL? Is it the same as is in SQL?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/sqlcheatsheet

Comment: https://dataexplorer.azure.com/home

Answer (score 1):

The way you query in Kusto is a bit different. You start with the dimension you want to query, which should be equivalent to the 'FROM' in SQL.

E.g.

```
StormEvents
| where isnotempty(EndLocation) 
| summarize event_count=count() by EndLocation
| top 10 by event_count
```

for joins, the synthax is a bit different too. You may find good samples in the official doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/joinoperator?pivots=azuredataexplorer